# How to pick up the arguments in a new Modeless Dialogue?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm creating a modeless dialogue with the JavaScript command:-

```
function OpenGradeDialog(text_to_display)
{
    var winArgs = new Array(text_to_display);
    var winSettings = 'center:yes;resizable:no;help:no;...etc';
    window.showModelessDialog('MyForm.aspx', winArgs, winSettings);
}
```

but somehow need to pick up the value of the supplied argument 'text_to_display' in MyForm.aspx. For preference I'd like to pick it up in the codebehind but in the .aspx would do. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I have worked round this problem by having the main program write a scratch file containing the needful information for the modeless dialogue to read. I wouldn't dream of calling this ghastly hack a solution, which is why I'm posting this as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access it from the code-behind then you can simply add a `<asp:HiddenField>` to your `MyForm.aspx` view. For example:

```
 <asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="hdnTextToDisplay" ClientIDMode="static" />
```

Populate this with your `text_to_display` as part of your `Javascript`.

You will now be able to access the `hdnTextToDisplay.Value` in your code-behind on postback.

Note that the `ClientIDMode` property on the `hiddenField` will stop `.Net` from changing the `ID` of the `HiddenField` when it renders it.

you can populate this field using javascript, so somewhere in your javascript function you can do something like this- assuming text_to_display is a string:

```
document.getElementById("hdnTextToDisplay").value = text_to_display;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Call me stupid, but could you explain how I might populate this HiddenField, as I'm not having any luck at the moment?

Comment: thanks again, but just for the avoidance of doubt, which Javascript is it supposed to go in and where? I've tried it in all possible places in the above, and also in the MyForm.aspx setting it to `window.dialogArguments[0];` and the result is always `Microsoft JScript runtime error: document.getElementById(...) is null or not an object`.